# Помогите решить задачу по js

Tags: javascript

*Условие*

Напиши класс *StringBuilder*. На вход он получает один параметр - строку, которую записывает в свойство `_value`.

*Добавь классу следующий функционал*:

- геттер `value` - возвращает текущее значение поля `_value`;
- метод `append(str)` - получает параметр `str` (строку) и добавляет ее в конец `_value`;
- метод `prepend(str)` - получает параметр `str` (строку) и добавляет ее в начало value;
- метод `pad(str)` - получает параметр `str` (строку) и добавляет ее в начало и в конец `_value`.

```
const builder = new StringBuilder('.');

builder.append('^');
console.log(builder.value); // '.^'

builder.prepend('^');
console.log(builder.value; // '^.^'

builder.pad('=');
console.log(builder.value; // '=^.^='
```

Вот мое решение:

```js
'use strict';
class StringBuilder {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  get value() {
    return this.value;
  }

  append(str) {
    this.value.push(str);
  }

  prepend(str) {
    this.value.unshift(str);
  }
  // додає елемент на поч і в кін
  pad(str){
    this.value.unshift(str);
  }
}

const builder = new StringBuilder('.');

// const value = builder.value();
// console.log(this.value);

builder.append('^');
console.log(builder.value); // '.^'


builder.prepend('^');
console.log(builder.value; // '^.^'
```

Comment: Дооформите ваш вопрос, пожалуйста. А также перепроверьте, ваше решение выдаёт ошибки в консоли.

Comment: да в коде были ошыбки:

Comment: я их справила ()-закритие скоб. У меня в консоле такая ошыбка-task-4.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property value of #<StringBuilder> which has only a getter
    at new StringBuilder   Я просто думала что можно использовать только get

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, тебе сказали, что строка - это массив символов) Но это не значит, что строка поддерживает те же методы, что и массив)

```
   class StringBuilder {
    constructor(value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    get val() {
      return this.value;
    }

    set val(value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    append(str) {
      this.value += str;
    }

    prepend(str) {
      this.value = str + this.value;
    }
    // додає елемент на поч і в кін
    pad(str) {
      this.value = str + this.value + str;
    }
  }
```

Comment: спасибо огромное) Вы мой спаситель) Оказывается надо думать не так сложно как я)

Comment: на здоровье, только пометь, что ответ помог, нажав на голочку слева-сверху от ответа)

Comment: я так и сделала сразу)